# Error on update [overwrite]

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.12.2-1+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstjpegformat.so', which is also in package gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 1.10.4-1ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.12.2-1+b1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64 (1.12.2-1+b1) over (1.10.4-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.12.2-1+b1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0', which is also in package libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 1.10.4-1ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.12.2-1+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.12.2-1+b1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the deb package you downloaded has programs that are included in a different package supplied by the ubuntu  repo.

You  have to stay with the packages in Ubuntu's repo. or download and replace all of the gstreamer-plugin packages.

Comment: ` trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0.so.0', which is also in package libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 1.10.4-1ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad_1.12.2-1+b1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0_1.12.2-1+b1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)  `

** this is the exact error. **